# check or not to check

Tags: jquery

I need a little bit help. Here is my url : http://fuzzysiberians.com/cfm/testRT.cfm

First, the Final check box should not be available until all of the task (1-8) boxes are checked. Second, the bills paid should not be available until final box is checked.

I have couple problems.

1. I check all of the taks. Then, I check final. If I uncheck any of the tasks, the final should be unchecked and disabled. The bills paid should also be unchecked and disabled. 
   For some reason, I cannot remove ID-9 (final) and ID-10 (bills paid) from my jtIDList.

I will really appreciate if somebody can point what I am doing wrong.

thanks

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqModal.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqModal.js" ></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js" ></script>
    <script>
    $().ready(function() {

        $('#jqmInvoice').jqm({modal: true, 
                      onHide: function(h) {
                          h.w.slideUp("fast",function() { if(h.o) h.o.remove(); }); 
                           $('#jobTypes-10').attr('checked',false);
                      },
                      trigger: false});

        $('#jqmReadyCheck').jqm({modal: true, 
                                 onHide: function(h) {
                                 /* callback executed on window hide. Hide notice, overlay. */
                                   h.w.slideUp("fast",function() { if(h.o) h.o.remove(); }); 
                                $('#jobTypes-9').attr('checked',false);
                                $('#chk-10').attr('disabled', true);
                                $('#desc-10').css('color','gray');
                                },                            
                                trigger: false});

        var arr = [];    


            $('#jobTypes-9').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#jobTypes-9').attr('checked',false);
            $('#desc-9').css('color','#ccc');





            $('#jobTypes-10').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#desc-10').css('color','#ccc');


        $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function() {
            var jtID = $(this).val();
            var inx = $.inArray(jtID, arr);
            if(inx == -1) {
                arr.push(jtID);
            }
            $("#jtIDList").val(arr);
            isReady(arr);
        });

        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
            var jtID = $(this).val();
            $('#jtIDVal').val(jtID);
            var inx = $.inArray(jtID, arr);
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                arr.splice(inx,1);
                arr.splice($.inArray(9,arr),1);
                //arr.splice($.inArray(10,arr),1);

                $("#jtIDList").val(arr);
            } else {
                if( inx == -1) {
                    arr.push(jtID);
                    $("#jtIDList").val(arr);    
                }
                if ( jtID == 10 ) {
                    $('#jqmInvoice').jqmShow().css('left',100).css('top',150); 
                }

            }

            isReady(arr);

        });

        function isReady(arr) {
            $('#image').html('jtIDList length:'+arr.length);
            if(arr.length < 8) {
                $('#desc-9').css('color','#ccc');
                $('#jobTypes-9').attr('checked',false);
                $('#jobTypes-9').attr('disabled', true);

                $('#jobTypes-10').attr('checked',false);
                $('#jobTypes-10').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#desc-10').css('color','#ccc');
            } else {
                $('#desc-9').css('color','#000');
                $('#jobTypes-9').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }

        $('#jobTypes-9').click(function() {
            if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                $('#jobTypes-10').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#desc-10').css('color','#000');
            } else {
                $('#jobTypes-10').attr('checked',false);
                $('#jobTypes-10').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#desc-10').css('color','#ccc');
            }
        });



     });
    </script>

    <form id="rtForm" name="rtForm" method="post" action="">
    userid: <input type="text" name="unid" id="unid" value="2990" /><br/>
    IDList:<input type="text" name="jtIDList" id="jtIDList" value="" /> <br/>
    selected jtID:<input type="text" name="jtIDVal" id="jtIDVal" value="" /> <br/>        
    pjtIDList:<input type="text" name="pjtIDList" id="pjtIDList" value="2,3,6" /><br/> 
    <div style="float:left; padding-left:10px;">
    <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">

        <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="image"></div></td></tr>
        <tr>
              <td align="left" id="desc-1"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 1
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-1" width="40" class="refTbl">
               <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-1" value="1"   />
              </td>

              <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="left" id="desc-2"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 2 
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-2" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-2" value="2" checked="checked"  />
              </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
              <td align="left" id="desc-3"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 3
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-3" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-3" value="3" checked="checked"  />
              </td>

              <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="left" id="desc-4"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 4
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-4" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-4" value="4"   />
              </td>
        </tr>  

        <tr>
              <td align="left" id="desc-5"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 5
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-5" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-5" value="5"   />
              </td>

              <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="left" id="desc-6"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 6
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-6" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-6" value="6" checked="checked"  />
              </td>
        </tr>  

        <tr>
              <td align="left" id="desc-7"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
               Task 7
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-7" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-7" value="7"   />
              </td>

              <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="left" id="desc-8"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Task 8
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-8" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-8" value="8"   />
              </td>
        </tr>  

        <tr>
              <td align="left" id="desc-9"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Final
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-9" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-9" value="9"   />
              </td>

              <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="left" id="desc-10"  width="90" class="refTbl" >
                  Bills Paid
              </td>
              <td align="left" id="chk-10" width="40" class="refTbl">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="jobTypes" id="jobTypes-10" value="10"   />
              </td>
        </tr>  
    </table> 
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="formSub" align="right" style="padding-right:20px;">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSaveRT" id="btnSaveRT" class="submitButton save" value="Save" style="margin-left:20px;"/>
    </div>
    </form>

<div id="jqmInvoice" class="jqmWindow" style="width:430px; display:none;">
<div class="jqmHeader" >
    <div id="jqmInvoiceTitle" style="margin-top:10px;">Confirmation for Paid Bills</div>
    <div id="jqmHeaderClose" style="margin-top:-10px;" >
        <img src="images/vista-close.gif" class="jqmClose" alt="close" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
     <div class="jqmBody">
     <div class="jqmConfirmContent">
       <div style="float:left; padding-top:20px;">
              <img src="images\warning.gif" />
       </div>
       <div style="float:left; padding-left:20px; width:300px;">
           <p class="jqmConfirmMsg">
           This will notify the bank that all bills have been paid. 
           </p>
           <p>Do you wish to continue?</p>
       </div>
       <div style="clear:both; height:10px;"></div>
    </div>
        <div style="padding-left:52px;">
        <input type="submit" name="btnNo"  id="btnNo"  class="submitButton no"  value="NO" />
        <input type="submit" name="btnYes" id="btnYes" class="submitButton yes" value="YES" style="margin-left:50px;" />
    </div>
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="jqmFooter jqmFooterButtons" id="jqmFooterText">
     </div>
</div>
<script>
        $('#btnNo').click(function() {
    $('#jqmInvoice').jqmHide();        
    $('#jobTypes-10').attr('checked',false);
    $('#formSub').html('<input type="submit" name="btnSaveRT" id="btnSaveRT" class="submitButton save" value="Save" style="margin-left:20px;"/>');
});
$('#btnYes').click(function() {
    $('#jqmInvoice').jqmHide();
    $('#jobTypes-10').attr('checked',true);
});
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of just the link. Thanks.

Comment: well, it's jquery, so the code is all there...

Comment: Updated my code, fixed the first issue. The new problem is, if the all the tasks is checked, then it should make final box available.

Comment: @patrick @mgroves - Thanks for asking that. I don't know about other people, but I don't usually just click random links in a post. I usually like to see code (and whether or not the person understands their solution enough to at least have focused down the problem within their code).

Comment: @mgroves - Point is that the code should be *here*. These questions are intended to have some potential benefit to future readers. The link may not exist a year from now, but the content of the question will.

Comment: sorry, updated the original post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

this seem to work, changed checkbox click function:

```
   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
            var jtID = $(this).val();
            $('#jtIDVal').val(jtID);
            var inx = $.inArray(jtID, arr);
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                arr.splice(inx,1);

            for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i] == 9) {    
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i] == 10) {    
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }    

                // arr.splice($.inArray(10,arr),1);

                $("#jtIDList").val(arr);
            } else {
                if( inx == -1) {
                    arr.push(jtID);
                    $("#jtIDList").val(arr);    
                }
                if ( jtID == 10 ) {
                    $('#jqmInvoice').jqmShow().css('left',100).css('top',150); 
                }

            }

            isReady(arr);

        });
```

Comment: `input:checkbox` is a quicker to write and easier to read option vs `input[type=checkbox]` ==> http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified if you add a class to the details, one to the final and one to the bills paid (or just use the ID on the last two) as:

EDIT:(Note, if you add more details, it adjusts to the new detail checkboxes as I have it).  My example is a tiny bit verbose, but that is to clearly show the intent here.

```
$('.billfinal:checkbox')[0].checked = false;
$('.billspaid:checkbox')[0].checked = false;
$('.billfinal:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
$('.billspaid:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);

$('.billdetail').click(function() {
    if ($('.billdetail:checked').length < $('.billdetail:checkbox').length) {
        $('.billfinal:checkbox')[0].checked = false;
        $('.billspaid:checkbox')[0].checked = false;
        $('.billfinal:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.billspaid:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.billfinal:checkbox').attr('disabled', false);
    };
});
$('.billdetail').trigger('click'); //set value based on initial checked count
$('.billfinal').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.billspaid:checkbox').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
       $('.billspaid:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
    };
});
```

See it working here:http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/1/

Comment: very nice. edited your jsfiddle to include : $('.billspaid:checkbox').attr('checked', false);

Comment: I see your point on the addition, but I did not want to make that assumption and it was set in the original line 2 of the code.  NOTE: I used different methods to set the value there just to show as an example, your syntax works also to set the values.